# Is it possible to fit "The Fire Within The Ways" within the canon timeline?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Brandon Sanderson has made it quite clear that *The Fire Within The Ways*, a "deleted scene" from *A Memory of Light* which was recently published in the *Unfettered III* anthology, is *not* canon.

However, I'd like to pretend that it is for head-canon purposes.

Is there *any* kinda sorta plausible way that *The Fire Within The Ways* could fit into the primary story's timeline, without any direct factual contradictions?

Please mark spoilers.

Comment: This question might be better asked in the inverse: "If we ignore Brandon Sanderson's statement, are there any factual or timeline contradictions between _The Fire Within The Ways_ and the rest of _The Wheel of Time_ which would cause problems with canon?

Comment: @gowenfawr "Are there any factual or timeline contradictions?" Yes, there is, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/WoT/comments/9530a6/its_happening_the_ways_will_be_cleansed/e3pw2b2/. Question is, is there a workaround?

Comment: I think, as he states in that link, you're going to just have to pretend if you want it.